# Bean can't access another defined bean even after using ApplicationContextAware

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring and I am trying to learn how to use ApplicationContextAware,
so i have these two class number.java and number2.java, all in the same package

number implements ApplicationContextAware and overrides

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context), 
where it saves the context in a private ApplicationContext variable - **context**.

I have defined the following three beans in a JavaConfig file

```
package org.penta.test1;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class numConfig {

@Bean(name="number3")
public number2 getNumber3()
{
    return new number2(7);
}

@Bean(name="number1")
public number getNumber()
{
    return new number(5);
}

@Bean(name="number2")
public number getNumber2()
{
    number n = new number();
    n.reset();
    return n;
}


}
```

There is a problem in creating the bean number2, 
this is what the reset() code does inside number.java

```
public void reset()
{
    number2 n2 = (number2)context.getBean("number3");
    n = n2.getNum();
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
Exception caught - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'number2' defined in org.penta.test1.numConfig2: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.penta.test1.number]: Factory method 'getNumber2' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I can't seem to realize what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

If i remove the number2 bean definition then the code works fine, no errors.
I can't seem to understand why number.java even after being aware of it's context can't find the number3 bean which has been defined in the same context.

Comment: Ofcourse it will fail... There is nothing injected yet after object construction.

Comment: Can you explain? I am creating a default number object inside number2, calling it's reset() [which copies the value inside a number2 bean into a number bean] method, and returning the object.

Comment: When do you think Spring will be able to inject the `ApplicationContext` into your bean. It doesn't even know about that instance at the point you are calling `reset`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I put in a few print statements and realized, the setBeanName and setApplicationContext methods are called at the very end of the object instantiation, ergo during reset, the object doesn't even realize it's a bean, so the reference is foreign to it. Do tell me if I got anything wrong.

Comment: They aren't called at the end but after the object instantiation. They are called as soon as it is detected as bean which is only after the method finished creating it (the `@Bean` method acts as a factory method for your object) and it has returned the object,

Comment: Ok, that explains a lot, but tell me something, If I am doing an xml config, then I wouldn't be having this problem would I?

Comment: Well that depends on what you are doing. If you put this in a factory bean you still have the same issue. If you have some `Bean(Factory)PostProcessor` which operate early on the object instance you might again have this issue. But reygurlay speaking you wouldn't have this issue because you simply aren't able to call the reset method that early in the process.

Comment: Yeah I realize a bean factory employs lazy loading. My question is, if I am using an applicationContext, no pre/post processors, and say I have 2 beans - bean1 and bean2 described inside my xml(which is being called in my ClassPathXmlApplicationContext), and I have a similar reset() method inside the class of bean1, which tries to access bean2 through the passed context. Would that still throw an exception?

Comment: No because you wouldn't be able to call the reset method before the bean has been properly initialized.

Comment: Ok, that clears things up a lot. Thanks man